# grub-mkconfig can't find windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, antergos

I have two SSDs in my PC, one with a working Windows 10 on, and the other a fresh install of Antergos.
Booted Antergos up to get grub set up with both installs, but having difficulties there.
I have mounted Windows via the file manager, so I can see all my Windows files. I have then ran `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` which unfortunately does not pick up Windows.

`Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/Antergos-Default/theme.txt
Found Intel Microcode image
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initramfs image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
done`

Tried running os-prober, and that also does not find it. 
[image: Drive information]

Not sure if anything there is massively incorrect. But this SSD previously had Debian on until today. So I have dual boot working fine before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not easy to solve correctly while each device and distro has its own unique but I'll make a try

when you mounted the windows partition go to terminal and check on what partition windows is mounted by

```
fdisk -l
```

in the output notice the partition that has NTFS file system (mostly is only used by windows)
let's say it's (e.g /dev/sdb2)

then

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

then take the little string you find that is associated with your partition (e.g /dev/sdb2) the string will be something like (AC46D28646D250A6)

now edit /etc/grub.d/40_custom in your favorite text editor (if not found then you need to find a file that's responsible to add boot entry in your linux distro)

at the bottom of 40_custom add this lines by replacing my string of(AC46D28646D250A6) with your own ofcource

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod search_fs_uuid
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root AC46D28646D250A6
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

then go to /boot/grub2 and make a backup of your current `grub.cfg`
and now

```
grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

and make a reboot to check if windows is added now to your boot entry menu

and also notice that the options provided in 40_custom(or your unique file) may have to be changed in order to match your machine state

Comment: The Antergos installation is on a GPT-partitioned disk that has `/boot/efi` on it. This is a pretty strong hint that Antergos is booting in EFI style. The Windows system disk has MBR partitioning, indicating that Windows is booting in old BIOS style. The `ntldr` GRUB command comes from similarly-named GRUB module, which only exists in `i386-pc` (=BIOS) version of GRUB, not in the EFI version. So unfortunately I don't think this is going to work in this case.

Comment: @telcoM What is weird here is that the SSD that has Linux on has, previously had Antergos on, then Debian and now going back to Antergos (which is where the issue started), no changes have been made to Windows.  
Can you think of a way to get Antergos to work with the Windows drive without making changes to the drive itself? 
I have checked through the BIOS settings and can't see anything that jumps out at me as an issue.

Comment: @louay-alosh this is something I was looking at doing, but wasn't too sure of the correct steps. Thanks for the write up, I will look into this.

Comment: When starting an operating system installer from e.g. a DVD, modern EFI-capable systems can show *two* boot options for it: one for legacy BIOS boot style, and another for EFI. Unfortunately it is not always clearly identifiable which is which. Even more unfortunate is that the boot method of the installer will usually also decide the boot method of the OS to be installed: an installer started in BIOS style has no access to firmware EFI boot variables and so cannot fully install an EFI style bootloader. An installer booted in EFI could perform a legacy installation but has no reason to.

Comment: @telcoM Interesting. Since my BIOS settings are exactly what they were when I installed Windows 10, which appears to be in the old style. I would have assumed that means Linux would load the old boot style?   
My main source of confusion is I installed Debian last week, to the same drive I am installing Antergos to, and it was all smooth. Granted different Linux, but would have though its similar in installation
Would it be easier to install Windows 10 with UEFI?

Comment: The important thing is to have all the operating systems in a multi-boot system use *the same boot style*. The selection between legacy an UEFI boot method within the firmware is a pretty significant "fork in the road": once it's been passed, it may be impossible to switch from one path to the other without fully rebooting again. Unlike traditional BIOS style, UEFI has standardized provisions for coexistence of multiple OSs in one computer, so reinstalling Windows with UEFI style would reduce the chance of it "helpfully" overwriting GRUB to "fix Windows boot problems".

Comment: @telcoM That's what I was thinking, I did a windows repair before and it went and did some stuff with MBR, which I imagine would have caused issues anyway. 
So I would need to set my BIOS to UEFI, and then reinstall Windows that way?